# Regression line on a ggplot is not shown

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression

When I try to use ggplot, the plot just shows data in dots, but there is no line at all in the plot. Also, there is no error in R. Data has two columns, `Month` and `Rainfall`.

I made dataset as following for several years:

```
Month Rainfall
1        0.7
2         0
3         0
.         .
.         .
12         1.2
1         0
2         0.2
.         .
.         .
```

The full code for ggplot of my project is as follow :

```
 split = sample.split(dataset$Rainfall, SplitRatio = 0.8)
 training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
 test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)


 regressor = lm(formula = Rainfall ~ Month,
                data = training_set)

 y_pred = predict(regressor, newdata = test_set)
 y_pred


 library(ggplot2)

 ggplot() + 
   geom_point(aes(x = training_set$Month, y = training_set$Rainfall),
               color = 'red') +
   geom_line(aes(x = training_set$Month, y = predict(regressor, newdata = training_set)),
               color = 'blue') +
   ggtitle('Rainfall (Training set)') +
   xlab('Month') +
   ylab('Rainfall')

 ggplot() + 
   geom_point(aes(x = test_set$Month, y = test_set$Rainfall),
               color = 'red') +
   geom_line(aes(x = training_set$Month, y = predict(regressor, newdata = training_set)),
               color = 'blue') +
   ggtitle('Monthly Rainfall (Test set)') +
   xlab('Month') +
   ylab('Rainfall')
```

But, I cannot plot a line as simple linear regression.

Comment: You could using `geom_abline` to plot the regression linea based on its intercept and slope

Comment: use geom_smooth(method = 'lm') to plot a regression line between your x and y variables

Comment: There might be something wrong with your regressor.. can you share the code on how that is fitted? And also dput(test_set) and paste the output as part of your post to share the output?

Comment: And also, what is in training_set?

Answer (score 0):

For ggplot2 you can use *geom_smooth(method="lm")* to plot a simple linear regression line.

You may refer to this https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/data-visualization-2.1.pdf cheat-sheet for how to use ggplot2.

---

Example of a '*fixed*' version of your code:

```
library(tidyverse)
test_set %>% ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Rainfall)) + 
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) +
   ggtitle('Monthly Rainfall (Test set)') +
   xlab('Month') +
   ylab('Rainfall')
```

I used this as the test_set

```
test_set <- tribble(
  ~Month, ~Rainfall,
  1,   1,
  2,   2,
  3,   3,
  4,   2,
  5,  .7
)
```

[image: Example of code above]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry to say this,I try your code,but it does not work at all.

Comment: @R_mad it should work I made an edit, and provide the example output.

Comment: Yeh for you works, but I want to have my test as I have already shown in this post. I think it does not draw a line because I have several values for each month. But in your example there are only one value for each month.

Comment: No it doesn't matter if there are several values for each month.